# AttributeError at /accounts/login/ 'CustomLoginForm' object has no attribute 'email_field'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to login user via email and password.
I'm unable to do that. Please Help me to fix this issue. I shall be very thankful to you.
I tried to use some authenticate stuff and try to login the user but getting multiple email value.

forms.py

```
class CustomLoginForm(forms.Form):
      
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        label='',
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={'autocomplete': 'email', 'placeholder': 'Enter your email'}
        )
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        label='',
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password', 'placeholder': 'Password'}
        )
    )

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(email)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }


    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
        The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.
        """
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set the max length and label for the "username" field.
        self.email = User._meta.get_field(User.EMAIL_FIELD)
        email_max_length = self.email_field.max_length or 254
        self.fields['email'].max_length = email_max_length
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['maxlength'] = email_max_length
        if self.fields['email'].label is None:
            self.fields['email'].label = capfirst(self.email_field.verbose_name)


    # class Meta:
    #     model = User
    #     fields = ['email','password']
    

    def authenticate(self,request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if email is None:
            email = kwargs.get(User.EMAIL_FIELD)
        if email is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = User._default_manager.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            User().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        """
        Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
        that attribute are allowed.
        """
        is_active = getattr(user, 'is_active', None)
        return is_active or is_active is None

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if email is not None and password:
            self.user_cache = self.authenticate(self.request, email=email, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        """
        Controls whether the given User may log in. This is a policy setting,
        independent of end-user authentication. This default behavior is to
        allow login by active users, and reject login by inactive users.
        If the given user cannot log in, this method should raise a
        ``ValidationError``.
        If the given user may log in, this method should return None.
        """
        if not user.is_active:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',
            )

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache

    def get_invalid_login_error(self):
        return ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
            code='invalid_login',
            params={'email': self.email_field.verbose_name},
        )
```

models.py

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

If more code is require then tell me in a comment section , I will update my question with that information.

[Traceback](https://dpaste.com/5FCMU64Q9)

Comment: `authenticate(self, email=None, password=None, **kwargs)` change this to `authenticate(self, request=None,email=None, password=None, **kwargs)`. Also `user = User._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(email)` this won't work unless your email is set as the `USERNAME_FIELD` so you should instead write `user = User._default_manager.get(email=email)`

Comment: Oky I have done that , but getting  ```AttributeError at /accounts/login/ 'CustomLoginForm' object has no attribute 'email_field'```

Comment: Change `self.email = User._meta.get_field(User.EMAIL_FIELD)` to `self.email_field = User._meta.get_field(User.EMAIL_FIELD)`

Comment: It removed that traceback , But Still not loging me in, I put email and password ,then click to login but not logging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [**`AuthenticationForm`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L160) is *not* a `ModelForm`, but a simple form, so adding a `Meta` does not make much sense: it will not construct form fields.

What you will need to do is define the (extra) form fields in your form, so:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _

class CustomLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        label='',
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={'autocomplete': 'email', 'placeholder': 'Enter your email'}
        )
    )
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = ('Password')
        self.fields['password'].label = ''
```

This will however still include the `username` since we *inherit* this from the parent user. Likely it is better to construct a simple form, and look at the `AuthenticationForm` to implement part of the logic:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _

class CustomLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        label='',
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={'autocomplete': 'email', 'placeholder': 'Enter your email'}
        )
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        label='',
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password', 'placeholder': 'Password'}
        )
    )

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is None:
            raise ValidationError('No combination of email and password found')
        self.user = user
        return self.cleaned_data
```

In the view, we can then use the [**`login(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login):

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomLoginForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.user
            auth_login(request, user)
            # …
        else:
            # …
    # …
```

We should implement a backend that can work with an email address, like:

```
# appname/backends.py

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

UserModel = get_user_model()

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        if email is None or email is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get(email=email)
        except (UserModel.DoesNotExist, UserModel.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

we can then set this as a backend by specifying the [**`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#authentication-backends):

```
# settings.py

# …

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'appname.backends.EmailBackend'
]

# …
```

Comment: More methods of `AuthenticationForm` would need to be overriden if the OP wants to use it. For instance in `clean` it uses the `username` field to authenticate the user, etc.

Comment: Well this thing is not working properly. Because when i'm trying to login with email it is not logging me in.. Why this is happening ?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, I think subclassing will require too much work, and it would also easily break if later it is updated, so I guess it is better to implement a simple form, and perhaps look how it is implemented in GitHub and copy part of the logic.

Comment: @dummyfirst: because as the source code in GitHub indicates, it will try to look for the username. You will need to copy in the authentication logic and modify it from the `AuthenticationForm`.

Comment: @dummyfirst also If you haven't implemented a Custom User model with email being `USERNAME_FIELD` or implemented a custom authentication backend the call to `authenticate` will also not work.

Comment: So what should I do now , Should i remove everything related to login part and use custom approach from models....

Comment: @dummyfirst: models? No you will need to update the authentication. This can be done by implementing a custom `clean` method in the form, or in the view where you extract the values from the form.

Comment: Okay. Let me see.

Comment: @dummyfirst this part in [ModelBackend - GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0c7e880e13b837dd76276c04ebdc338bb76d1379/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L36) is basically how authenticate method works. You can either implement a custom backend or bring this logic (with respect to email) into the clean method.

Comment: Thank You both of you AbdulAzizBarkat and WillenVanOnsem , I'm just gonna try to do that. If I stuck somewhere please help me, I just want to complete the login part today.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have tried the way you said, Please look at my question once again. And guide me.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I also tried to implement the authenticate function inside the form class, but Still having an issue , I have updated my question , Please have a look and help me .

Comment: @dummyfirst: I think you are making things too complicated, you can authenticate by calling `authenticate` in the clean method. You will still need to log in the user in the view with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `authenticate(email=email, password=password)` will only work if email is the `USERNAME_FIELD` or a custom Authentication backend is used (considering the default `ModelBackend`'s code). Looking at dummyfirst's model he doesn't do anything to the username field.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, but it would be bad design to implement authentication code in the form. That simply belongs in a backend.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's true, if you don't mind I would add an implementation of a Custom Backend to your answer?